# Go to previous Tab using button in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

How to go previous tab if I click back button?
XAML

```
<Button x:Name="btnBack" Margin="239,418,333,11 Click="btnBack_Click">
    <Button.Template>         
        <ControlTemplate>                    
            <Image x:Name="backImg" Source="Images/back.png" />                
        </ControlTemplate>           
    </Button.Template>        
</Button>
```

Code

```
private void btnBack_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)     
{
}
```

Tab item

```
<TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="403" BorderThickness="0" 
            Background="Transparent" Margin="10,10,0,0"
            VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="622">       
    <TabItem Header="List" Margin="0,0,-19,0">     
        //object    
    </TabItem>        
    <TabItem Header="Register" Margin="0,0,-19,0">    
    </TabItem>    
    //object    
</TabControl>
```

It is possible to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the [TabControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tabcontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object you have a SelectedIndex that you can use to navigate to any element within the list. Try something like the following:

```
private void btnBack_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)     
{
    if (tabControl.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        tabControl.SelectedIndex -= 1;
    }
}
```

In this case we are calling the tab control, checking if we can reverse in the items it has and if we can we will go backward by 1 item.

Keeping in mind that your XAML TabControl needs to be given a name to be called by from the code behind:

```
<TabControl x:Name="tabControl">
```

Comment: No problem @Un-Known. :) Don't forget to mark as answered, if it answers your question.